# html site completely full screen similar to flash full screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, html, fullscreen

I made a html5 video gallery that is going to be used as a kiosk. I now need it to be viewed in complete full screen mode with no tool bars, similar to when a flash site is in full screen. Is there a way to do this with javascript or jQuery? I was also thinking of calling it from a iframe inside a full screen flash site but dont know if this is possible. Any suggestions will help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time no there is not without having the user press f11.  But there is an API in the works that is supposed to make this happen. [https://wiki.mozilla.org/index.php?title=Gecko:FullScreenAPI](https://wiki.mozilla.org/index.php?title=Gecko%3aFullScreenAPI)

Edit (Other options):
If you are wanting to work in kiosk mode then possibly John Kurlak's comment will help if you want to work in IE.  Also, you can use add-ons such as https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/r-kiosk/?src=search.  This way you can turn the browser into a kiosk and not worry about users getting back out.

Comment: You can make HTML fullscreen with window.createPopup() in IE6 and lower.  Or, if you use a version greater than IE6, you can, but only for locally run files.

Comment: I am going to be using the newest version of safari. Firefox's html5 video quality is not very good. Thanks

Comment: @user973671 well I don't know about the quality issue. I haven't had any problems with say youtube html5 videos on FF.  However there is one addon for safari that might help.  http://www.safariaddons.com/en-US/safari/search?q=kiosk&cat=all

Comment: I have looked into saft, but it is not supported in the new version of safari. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe a website can force a page to go fullscreen. You can however have the browser start fullscreened and as long as you do not open a separate window it will remain fullscreened.

Answer (score -1):

Could you not create it in a new window using  window.open(), passing in fullscreen=true?

Comment: This still creates a window with a title bar and address bar.